# Indy IdUDPClient.sendbuffer - False data in receive buffer

Tags: delphi, udp, indy

Im sending UDP packets using Indy's IdUDPClient component:

```
FIdUDPclient.sendbuffer( AIP, APort, FIdUDPBuffer );
Frecl := FIdUDPclient.receivebuffer( FIdRecBuff, FreceiveTimeout );
```

Right after i receive the answer.

Using wireshark while debugging the code showed that sometimes receivebuffer `FIdRecBuff` contains unexpected data.

For example, the received bytes reading with Wireshark: 
 
`45 02 57 00` 
But while debugging `FIdRecBuff`: 
`45 02 57 02`

The above code is running in a worker thread with one dedicated IdUDPClient instance. I send only the same 3 bytes and getting 4 bytes as answer from each of the three IP device.

I thought the problem is that im sending UDP packets for three different IP device with no delay so the answering from the IPs are not in order. <s>But indy's sendbuffer() method is blocking until receive so i dont understand.</s>

Can someone explain what scenarios/conditions can lead to this behavior?

Comment: this happens on indy tcp too, you need to know how many bytes to read beforehand. usually the way to fix that with indy is send the number of bytes beforehand, then read that number of bytes on receiving end. This problem is usually why indy programs hang when reading too.

Comment: there also is a problem with sending/receiving logic. you do one send, then 2 receives.. first to get buffer length, then buffer itself. it is an awkward method, need to get used to it.

Comment: @Tuncay Göncüoğlu I dont see how it receives twice. Frecl is just an integer that takes the return of the receivebuffer method.

Comment: If i put a 2sec delay between sending to the different IP addresses, then the receive buffer seems ok (same data as in wireshark)... I just dont understand because as i know the thread is blocked until the answer is received for the sent packet so the receiving order should be fine.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu: what you say only applies to TCP, not to UDP. UDP is message oriented, not stream oriented. In UDP, you just have to make sure the receiving buffer is large enough to receive a complete message or else you get a `(WSA)EMSGSIZE` error and the message is lost. `ReceiveBuffer()` returns the number of bytes actually read. The largest message size in UDP is 65507 bytes, so a 64K buffer will suffice if you don't know the actual size ahead of time. If you want to allocate the buffer to the exact size, but don't know the size, you can *peek* the next message before then reading it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Im sure the receiving buffer is enough, i set it in the constructor for 227bytes. In this case the answer is always only 4 bytes.
Can it be the problem, that after sending the UDP packet with sendbuffer() for a particular IP, the next call for receivebuffer() getting the answer of another IP device? If so, how can i wait until i get the answer from the correct IP (Before sending to the next IP)? Should i check for the IP address of the answer and thats all?

Comment: @tdiop since UDP is connection-less, yes it is possible to receive other packets before the intended packet. So you have to either 1) read in a loop until you get the expected packet, or 2) "connect" (statically associate) the socket to a specific IP so it can send to and read from only that IP and no other. `TIdUDPClient` supports both usages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you thats good to know but its raise so many questions. How can i check the IP address thats belong to actual received bytes? And for connecting, is connecting an unnecessary overhead in this situation? (Sending packets without delay to lets say 10-20 IP devices in every 3 seconds.) And lastly, what about the received packets, are they waiting in a spooler until they get processed? If so whats the maximum size of this spool?

Comment: @tdiop `ReceiveBuffer` has an overload that returns sender IP/port. `Connect` in UDP is just a static association of a peer IP/port, there is no actual connection. I suggest not handling each device one at a time in a serialized manner. Use `TIdUDPServer` instead to send out to all devices in one go, and then process replies in the `OnUDPRead` event as they arrive. And yes, there is a finite kernel buffer for receiving packets. If the buffer fills up, packets will be dropped. 10-20 4-byte packets every few seconds is not a lot, unless you are really slow in reading them.

Comment: Can the same IdUDPserver instance be used from different threads? Is it threadsafe?

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem with IdUDPserver is that i cannot decide if an IP device did not answer in a given time (like receivetimout with IdUDPClient). :/ Ok i found the ReceiveTimeout property of IdUDPserver but im using OnUDPread so i just cannot decide if some IP device did not answered (if its offline).

Comment: Once `TIdUDPServer` is active, theoretically you can send to different devices using the same Binding from multiple threads. Use an array to track timestamps of last send/receive, updated when you send a request and `OnUDPRead` receives a response. That will give you per-device status. Otherwise, use a separate thread per device, with a separate `TIdUDPClient` per thread, and lock them down to specific devices using `Connect()`, then you can use `ReceiveBuffer()` and `ReceiveTimeout` per thread.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What if i create only one instance of TIdUDPClient and checking the connection with that (setting Connect for every distant IP)? So i would ask the IP devices in a serial way? Would the changing of connect parameter (even <500ms in cases) be an overload?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can i alter the 'Host' and 'Port' properties after calling TUDPclient.Connect ?  I mean can i just call connect only for once and then alter the Host and Port later without calling .Connect again? Thank You Remy.

Comment: @tdiop no, you would have to call `Connect` each time, to update the Host/Port association of the underlying socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending packets to different hosts using `TIdUDPClient` in a serial manner -with the communication method im using-, the received packets from different hosts can 'interfere' with each other. UDP is a connectionless protocol so there is no any mechanism that can guarantee the right order of the receiving packets (not synchronous to sent packets) or the answering remote hosts.

For separating the received packets by remote hosts, the possible solutions are (thanks to Remy Lebeau):

- Checking the received packets for the remote IP thats correspond to the sent packet.
- Connect IdUDPClient to the remote IP. (`IdUDPClient.binding` then `IdUDPClient.Connect`)
- Using IdUDPServer for sending packets, reading the answers in event handler `OnUDPRead`.

(Yet the right order of the received packets from the same remote host is not guaranteed, but right now that is not my goal).

Comment: This does not guarantee the order of packets received. In UDP, packets may not arrive in the same order they are sent, depending on the network routes taken by each packet. Traffic over a local LAN is more likely to stay in order than traffic over the Internet. If ordering is important, the sender MUST provide an incrementing sequence number in the packet data so the receiver can reorder received packets as needed. This also helps the receiver detect and ignore duplicate packets, too. Since UDP has no acks, the receiver should ack each packet received so the sender can resend missing packets.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes my answer is totally wrong. I meant not packet order of the same remote host, i will edit my answer soon. Thanks for the correction.